# Exit Do Loop when ungrouping columns

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to ungroup columns.

I made the following loop. When there are no more columns to be deleted there is an error.

```
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consulta-Abast").Activate
    On Error GoTo erro1
    Cells.Select
    Do While Selection.Columns.Ungroup
    Loop
erro1:
    Range("A2:AZ500000").Delete
```

I also tried it like this, the first block worked, but I got the same error in the second block.

```
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WMS").Activate
    Cells.Select
    On Error GoTo erro
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        .Ungroup
        .ClearOutline
    End With
erro:
    Range("A2:AZ500000").Delete
        
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consulta-Abast").Activate
    Cells.Select
    On Error GoTo erroa
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        .Ungroup
        .ClearOutline
    End With
erroa:
    Range("A2:AZ500000").Delete
```

I need to exit the loop when there are no more columns to ungroup.

Comment: Why do you need to Select your the cells in the Worksheet? Cant you just use ActiveSheet.Coiumns.Ungroup without a loop? The reference for Ungroup isn't clear what result the method might return.

Comment: i cleared the loop but the On Error GoTo  doesn't work for the second sheet

Comment: Rather than edit in the answer, post it as a solution

Comment: @ldsouza  Using On Error Resume Next can cause you grief down the line. Better to test whether you have any groups before trying to ungroup. Then you don't need the error handling. I've given an outline in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

With DS_London comment I found a way to work that around

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WMS").Activate
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Columns.Ungroup
Range("A2:AZ500000").Delete
    
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Consulta-Abast").Activate
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Columns.Ungroup
Range("A2:AZ500000").Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

This intrigued me, as I have never really used groups. The Ungroup call on a range fails (inelegantly) if there is nothing to ungroup. You can use the OutlineLevel property on a Range to see if it has any groups before you try to ungroup anything. An ungrouped column has an OutlineLevel of 1. If a Range has some grouped cells and some ungrouped, the OutlineLevel property returns NULL, so we can test for this and keep going until OutlineLevel is 1 (or not NULL):

This procedure ungroups all columns in the active sheet, even if they are sub-grouped:

```
Option Explicit
Sub UngroupAll()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Columns

    Do While IsNull(rng.OutlineLevel)
        rng.Ungroup
    Loop
End Sub
```

NB. You don't have to select any cells.